# How to dismiss a dialog from another method

Tags: android

I have created a dialog which can be called from anywhere by supplying a title and message as follows:

```
public void alertbox(String title, String mymessage)
{   new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle(title)
        .setMessage(mymessage)
        .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.cancel,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                {   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {}
                })
        .show();
}
```

But I get a lockup when I try to dismiss the dialog from another method:

```
private void doCheck() {
    alertbox("status", getString(R.string.checking_license));
    mChecker.checkAccess(mLicenseCheckerCallback);

    alertbox.dismiss();
}
```

It is the alertbox.dismiss(); statement that causes the crash. Any ideas how to properly do this?

Comment: Can you give the error that appears in logcat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be as simple as calling `runOnUiThread`:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        alertbox.dismiss();
    }
});
```

if you are on the wrong thread. Although with your additional details, the problem is more simple. To give away the punchline:

```
public AlertDialog alertbox(String title, String mymessage) {   
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle(title)
        .setMessage(mymessage)
        .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.cancel,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {}
            })
        .show();
}
```

and:

```
private void doCheck() {
    AlertDialog alert = alertbox("status", getString(R.string.checking_license));
    mChecker.checkAccess(mLicenseCheckerCallback);
    alert.dismiss();
}
```

Although you probably don't want to both show and dismiss the dialog in the same method. Do you see how the above code is at least saving a reference to the dialog so that you can dismiss it later?

Comment: the .show works, presumably because it is in the same method as it was created in (alertbox). However, I want to close the alert after the     mChecker.checkAccess(mLicenseCheckerCallback);
line is completed in the method called doCheck.

Comment: Based on the code Ted provided, alertbox is a method, not an object.

Comment: @Corey, I think he has both a variable and a method named alertbox, since he is calling `alertbox.dismiss()`.

Comment: @Ted, .show works because each of the AlertDialog builder methods are returning a builder.  .show() returns an AlertDialog, which you need to save to a variable. Then you will be able to call alertbox.dismiss().

Comment: @Matthew I now see in my haste how i used my method name alertbox as a variable in alertbox.show(). What is the syntax for me to retrieve the the name of the AlertDialog from the .show statement?

Comment: .show() returns an AlertDialog. You can simply use `return` like I showed in my code, or use `alertbox = ` instead of the `return`.

Comment: @Matthew, I don't see how the 'return' code saves the dialog name for future reference in another method.  The alert.dismiss() cannot be resolved because it has been defined as a variable, only a method. If I create a new variable dialogName, how do I set it from a .show() statement?

Comment: `.show()` is not a statement. The entire method is one big line of code that is split into multiple lines. The last method invocation is `show`, and its return type is `AlertDialog`. Trust me, the code I wrote for your `alertbox` method will compile correctly and it will return an `AlertDialog`.

Comment: @Matthew, sorry but your 'return' method doesn't work as it gives me a 'cannot be resolved' on the alert.dismiss()..surely I misunderstand something you've said. I re-wrote it so that I use a global variable 'myDialog' like this:   public void alertbox(String title, String mymessage) 
    { myDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)  .....   and now I can use 'myDialog.dismiss(); in any other method. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 5):

I came across this issue also and wanted to share my solution for anyone who chooses not to use the above method.

Firstly I defined my AlertDialog along with the class variables:

```
private AlertDialog alertbox;
```

Then I initiate the AlertDialog wherever it is required:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("title");
builder.setMessage("message");

alertbox = builder.create();
alertbox.show();
```

Finally, due to orginally defining the AlertDialog as an instance variable, I can close the AlertDialog through any methods within the class.

```
private void dismissAlert()
{
    alertbox.dismiss()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would have alertBox return the dialog like so

```
public AlertDialog alertbox(String title, String mymessage)
```

Then wherever you call it you can keep reference to the returned dialog and dismiss it as needed.